# Pandas rolling with groupby

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I am using a rolling function with win_type as 'gaussian'. However, when i am taking the mean of the data I am receiving a type error. Not sure why this is happening since 'std' is a required input while using 'gaussian' window. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
TypeError: roll_mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'std'
```

I have included a sample dataset to recreate this issue

```
dummy_dta = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                      'value' : [2,3,4,1,4]})

dummy_dta.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(2, win_type = 'gaussian', min_period = 1).mean(std = 2)    # TypeError
dummy_dta.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(2, win_type = 'gaussian', min_period = 1).mean()    # Runs okay
```

Comment: both run OK on my system.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I restarted my kernel and run it again but I still get the same error. Not sure what I am missing on the system

Comment: Pandas version `1.0.1` here.

Comment: I am using an older version '0.24.2'. May be I can try to update the version and check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your version of pandas to the latest version 1.1.0, as pointed out the comments.

A good way to figure this out is to check [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), which contains a nearly identical example to yours using the .sum() method instead of .mean() but with the same parameters. So if your code breaks and the code in the documentation doesn't, then you probably need to update your version of pandas.

```
dummy_dta.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(2, win_type = 'gaussian', min_period = 1).mean(std = 2)
```

Output:

```
id   
A   0    NaN
    1    2.5
    2    3.5
B   3    NaN
    4    2.5
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

---

```
dummy_dta.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(2, win_type = 'gaussian', min_period = 1).mean()
```

Output:

```
id   
A   0    NaN
    1    2.5
    2    3.5
B   3    NaN
    4    2.5
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I updated the version and it worked fine. Thanks for the help